# using `stringr` to remove unusual characters in column names

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a peculiar dataframe where the column names are quoted and I want to extract whatever is between the quotes. I am trying to use `stringr` to do this but to no avail. How can I do this? (I'd also take a solution that doesn't use `stringr`.)

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)

# creating a dataframe with esoteric name
(df <- tibble::tribble(~`"x"`,
                "x"))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   `"x"`
#>   <chr>
#> 1 x

# checking the name of the column
colnames(df)
#> [1] "\"x\""

# my attempt (doesn't work)
stringr::str_remove_all(colnames(df), pattern = '^"\"|\""$')
#> [1] "\"x\""
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about expected output: This works like so.
   `\\W` matches everything that isn't a word.

```
  stringr::str_remove_all(names(df),"\\W")
[1] "x"
```

Comment: Yeah, no worries. This is just a minimal example. The actual data frame looks much different. This works! What does `"\\W"` do? Can you add an explanation for this in your answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Edited to added an explanation.

Comment: what do you mean by "X is not a legal name for a column" pls

Comment: @user20650 I may be wrong but I read somewhere that letters are not "legal" names in R. Hence the usual addition of numerals infront of such names. It appears not to be the case though!

Comment: you can use either numbers or letters as column names but it is easier to work with numbers by adding a letter in front of them (i.e. without backticks) -- so round the other way from your comment^^. I mean just about every column name use letters e.g. `names(mtcars)`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the correction. @user20650 actually I meant single letters but I tested and they still work fine.